# « Quelques rues, ainsi que la rue Montmartre, ont une belle tête et finissent en queue de poisson » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, latin, littérature, zoologie

> [...] Enfin, les rues de Paris ont des qualités humaines, et nous
>   impriment par leur physionomie certaines idées contre lesquelles nous
>   sommes sans défense. Il y a des rues de mauvaise compagnie où vous ne
>   voudriez pas demeurer, et des rues où vous placeriez volontiers votre
>   séjour. Quelques rues, ainsi que la rue Montmartre, ont une belle tête
>   et *finissent en queue de poisson*.
>
> [ Honoré de Balzac, [*Ferragus*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferragus), chef des [Dévorants](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9vorant/2), 1834,
>   sur [wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Ferragus), je souligne ]

Au [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poisson) on l'a avec finir/se terminer, pour « [t]ourner court, avoir une fin abrupte et décevante par rapport à ce qui précède » alors que [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/queue_de_poisson/65676/locution?q=finir%20en%20queue%20de%20poisson#165840) le note familier, omet l'idée de déception et parle d'absence de conclusion. C'est Balzac, dans l'extrait cité, qui introduit l'expression en français, qu'on associe au *desinat in piscem* de Horace dans son [Art poétique ou Épître aux Pisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Poetica_(Horace))<sup>1</sup>, dont on a déjà rendu le début en français par :

> Supposez qu'un peintre ait l'idée d'ajuster à une tête d'homme un cou
>   de cheval et de recouvrir ensuite de plumes multicolores le reste du
>   corps, composé d'éléments hétérogènes; si bien qu'un beau buste de
>   femme se terminerait en une *laide queue de poisson*.
>
> [ [Traduction](http://bcs.fltr.ucl.ac.be/HOR/PisonsTrad.html) de F. Richard (Paris, Garnier, 1944), je souligne. ]

C'est qu'a priori il y a une nuance entre se terminer en poisson et se terminer comme le poisson se termine ; par ailleurs l'absence du mot queue dans l'original en latin ne permet pas en soi de déterminer si cette sémantique y était présente ou non, pour quelque raison que ce soit, et c'est hors sujet de toutes façons. Mais on aimerait profiter du fait que Balzac, chez qui l'on atteste l'expression en 1833, emploie la locution dans l’œuvre citée pour décrire un lieu existant, afin d'essayer de déterminer comment son esprit de [visionnaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor%C3%A9_de_Balzac#Le_grand_projet_de_La_Com.C3.A9die_humaine) en parfaite maîtrise de sa langue articule l'expression concrètement, et ses référents.

---

En s'appuyant sur sa connaissance du Paris historique, peut-on expliquer si l'on pense objectivement que Balzac veut dire, au sujet de la rue Montmartre, qu'elle :

> Se termine mal
>  Se termine laidement
>  Se termine plus
>   étroitement
>  Se termine de manière décevante
>  Se termine comme
>   un cul-de-sac

- En quoi la rue Montmartre (a-t-elle ici une belle tête et) *finit-elle en
  queue de poisson* en 1833 : de quel sens s'agit-il exactement dans l'extrait de Balzac?
- Lesquels de ces éléments font partie de la sémantique de la locution généralement ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
Humano capiti ceruicem pictor equinam

iungere si uelit et uarias inducere plumas

undique collatis membris, ut turpiter atrum

[*desinat in piscem*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=507) mulier formosa superne,

spectatum admissi, risum teneatis, amici?
 
*De Arte Poetica liber*, [Horace](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace)</sub>

Comment: Voir aussi _desinat in piscem_ sur [Latin.SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1491)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'après Wikipedia: « *Ici, la tête de la rue est le haut de la rue, où se trouvait à l'époque de Balzac l'hôtel d'Uzès, tandis que la queue correspond aux premiers numéros actuels, au quartier Les Halles.* »

La fin de la rue Montmartre se situe donc derrière l'église Saint Eustache où se situait précisément l'ancienne halle aux poissons. Le poisson de mer arrivait à Paris par la rue Poissonnière puis la rue Montorgueil qui se termine comme la rue Montmartre devant cette halle aux poissons.

**La halle aux poissons, le matin**, Palais des beaux-arts de Lille.

[image: Lille PdBA gilbert halle poissons.jpg]
By Victor Gabriel Gilbert - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=30941563

On trouvait donc bien du poisson à la fin de la rue Montmartre.

Balzac fait un jeux de mots entre le sens propre qu'il détourne, finir en queue de poisson n'était utilisé jusque là que pour décrire des créatures réelles ou imaginaires comme les sirènes, et le sens figuré qu'il invente, la rue Montmartre commence de manière majestueuse avec de belles constructions comme l’hôtel d'Uzès (disparu aujourd'hui) et se termine abruptement et de manière très décevante, le marché aux poissons étant réputé comme étant le plus nauséabond du quartier des Halles. Les cinq propositions de la question sont toutes valables.